# How to link one word to a second word and then link the second word to a third word

Tags: tcolorbox, hyperlink

[image]

Here I want to link the words 'Round 1 Problem 1', 'Round 1 Problem 2' to the words 'A 1', 'A 2' of the second page (The picture just below). So that whenever I click on **Round 1 Problem 1** it takes me to **A 1**[image] Now again in the second page I want to link the word 'A 1' to the words of 'A 1' the third page (The picture just below) so that whenever I click on **A 1** on second page it takes me to the **Solution of the A 1**

[image]

I am using `hyperlink` and `hypertarget` for this. Here is the code i am using.

```
  colframe=black,colback=Chartreuse1,
  boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt}

\begin{center}
\section*{\huge{\underline{Round 1 Problems}}}
    \mybox{\hyperlink{R1P1}{Round 1 P1}} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 1 P2}\\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 1 P3} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 1 P4} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 1 P5}} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 1 P6} \\  \vspace{4mm}
\section*{\huge{\underline{Round 2 Problems}}}
    \mybox{Round 2 P1} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 2 P2} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 2 P3} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 2 P4} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 2 P5} \\ \vspace{4mm}
    \mybox{Round 2 P6} \\ \vspace{4mm}
\end{center} 


\mybox{{Problem 1 : }}
Prove the inequality which states that if you let $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$ be positive real numbers, with $n \geq 2,$ then you have the inequality
$$
\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}+x_{3}+\cdots+x_{n}}+\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}+x_{3}+x_{4}+\cdots+x_{n}}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n}}{x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n-1}} \geq \frac{n}{n-1}
$
```

Comment: We need some more information to help you. At least a some code which shows what are you using.

Comment: It sounds like tcolorbox can be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a `\hypertarget` inside a `\hyperlink`, if you want. But even the following works without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Jump to \hyperlink{Problem-1}{Problem~1}.

\bigskip

\hypertarget{Problem-1}{}\hyperlink{Solution-1}{\textbf{Problem~1}}.

\bigskip

\hypertarget{Solution-1}{\textbf{Solution~1}}.

\end{document}
```

Clicking on the first Problem 1 jumps you to **Problem 1**. Clicking on **Problem 1** jumps you to **Solution 1**. The key is to use unique target names.